# Creating react class with several components

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and can create components in different js files. But I would like to know if there is a way to create `Main` class with `sub1` and `sub2` components. And call components like this

```
import Main from './dir/main';



export default class Settings extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Main.sub1>

                <Main.sub2/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like that because you have an instance so you have to surround it

```
import Main from './dir/main';
import React from 'react';



export default class Settings extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
           <>
            <div>
                <Main.sub1 />
                <Main.sub2 />
            </div>
          </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, butu I don't know how to customize Main class

Comment: You could try to add props : like : this.props.name and after <Main name="Shaben" /> actually this is an example but you can to modify to be better and pass lots of args

Comment: or try with this.state.value depends what do you want to do